# Regular Expressions for number range and characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that matches a combination of a number (larger than 5, but smaller than 500) and a text string that comes after the number.

For example, the following matches would return true: 6 Items or 450 Items or 300 Items Red (there can be other characters after the word "Items")

Whereas the following strings would return false: 4 Items or 501 Items or 40 Red Items

I tried the following regex, but it doesn't work:

```
string s = "Stock: 45 Items";          
Regex reg = new Regex("5|[1-4][0-9][0-9].Items");
MessageBox.Show(reg.IsMatch(s).ToString());
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex should work for checking if number is in range from 5 to 500:

```
"[6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9][0-9]|500"
```

**Edit**: below example with more complex regex, which excludes numbers greater than 1000 too, and excludes strings other than " Items" after a number:

```
string s = "Stock: 4551 Items";
string s2 = "Stock: 451 Items";
string s3 = "Stock: 451 Red Items";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[^0-9]([6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9][0-9]|500)[^0-9]Items");

Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch(s).ToString()); // false
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch(s2).ToString()); // true
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch(s3).ToString()); // false
```

Comment: The second section matches 01, so you need to change the first digit to disallow 0.

Comment: @unholysampler: yes, you're right, I've edited solution to be correct

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately, your regex also returns true for numbers > 500 and how do I add the string (Items) to the regex?

Comment: Also doesn't [5-9] in the first case allow 5 as a valid value? wouldn't it be [6-9] (being that the value is not greater then 5)

Comment: @Rob: I've upgraded my answer, I hope new regex it will work better

Comment: @onaclow2000 I assumed that number 5 should pass but yes, you're right - it should't (regex corrected)

Comment: @Lucasus: There was an error on 3-digit numbers with a 0 in the center. Your `[1-9]` i suspect in the problem. Changing it to include 0 in the class should solve it. This is what I was using as well: `\s(?:[6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9][0-9]|500)\sItems$`

Comment: @Brad Christie: You're right, I've corrected regex. Not so easy to write one without errors after first shot ;) But should be OK now (If we assume that 500 is correct number, if not, we can simply remove the '500' part of regex)

Comment: @Lucasus: According to [this test](http://ideone.com/rPJxj) what you have now should be the winner. And I hear ya--at least we're not in the vacuum tube days, I'd be doing a LOT of walking catching those bugs.

Comment: That's exactly doing what I want. Great stuff - thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks...Its working...I made it for range 0 to 255


String regexStr = "[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-5]";

Answer (score 2):

The following method should do what you want.  It uses more than regular expressions.  But its intent is more clear.

```
// itemType should be the string `Items` in your example
public static bool matches(string input, string itemType) {
    // Matches "Stock: " followed by a number, followed by a space and then text
    Regex r = new Regex("^Stock: (\d+) (.*)&");
    Match m = r.Match(s);
    if (m.Success) {
        // parse the number from the first match
        int number = int.Parse(m.Groups[1]);
        // if it is outside of our range, false
        if (number < 5 | number > 500) return false;
        // the last criteria is that the item type is correct
        return m.Groups[2] == itemType;
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: I have to agree this answer seems like the most logical situation. Basically grab the value from the string, and do a numerical comparison. I don't see there being a clear Regex to do this, and clarity is a good thing when writing code!

Comment: @onaclov, glad you agree. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(([1-4][0-9][0-9])|(([1-9][0-9])|([6-9])))\sItems
```

Answer (score 0):

What about "\<500>|\<[1-9][0-9][0-9]>|\<[1-9][0-9]>|\<[6-9]>" , it works for me fine in linux shell so it should be similar in c#. they have a bug here on web, there should be backslash> after the sets ... e.g. 500backslash> :-)