# How to get a proper date from a text?

Tags: c#, regex

I have to find all date from a text file the text should be int form of **dd mm** or **mm dd** (i.e. 1. 10 January or 2. January 10) I have written this type of regex `(\d{2} January)` .It gives only 10 January but I want to write 

1. a single regex so that I can get the both date format (I have an option that i can write the same like this `(\d{2} January)|(January \d{2})`.)

2. a valid date number (I.e. My regex returns true if I have 99 January in my text but it is invalid).
cases that should match

- **1 Januar**y
- **02 January**
- **29 January**
- 32 January
- 2004 January
- January 2004
- January 32
- **January 29**
- **January 1**
- **January 01**

those are in bold case should valid match and other are invalid.

Comment: Use something like [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461637/regular-expressions-for-number-range-and-characters) and search by a range of numbers, not just any.

Comment: Can you add an example of your text?

Comment: Did you test the regex using `|` ? And how do you propose to figure out if February 29th is a valid date if you don't have the year in there? I would suggest you use regular expressions to find likely candidates, and then filter them using `new DateTime(y, m, d)` and catching exceptions.

Comment: Try this : (([12]\d|3[01]) January)|(January ([12]\d|3[01])).)

Comment: Actually, there are tons of similar questions. Please check for posts containing `extract date C#`, `validate datetime C#`, you will find all the building blocks for your case. You do not need to use a regex to validate a date, use `DateTime.TryParse`, thus regex can be basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern needs the month names only once:

```
\b((?<day>[0-2]?\d|3[01]) )?January(?(day)| ([0-2]?\d|3[01]))\b
```

[DEMO](http://goo.gl/uqEpnL)

But it matches for days from 0 to 31. The day patterns are:

- 0-31: [0-2]?\d|3[01]
- 0-30: [0-2]?\d|30
- 0-29: [0-2]?\d
- 0-28: [01]?\d|2[0-8]

Comment: Nice use of the conditional match.

Comment: @vera thanks, this ans looks good but when I put 2004 January its return true because 04 January match the condition.

Comment: @madan Yes of course - your question doesn't tell me something about years. You tried this regex `(\d{2} January)|(January \d{2})` and you don't want to match 99 but you want to match 2004? Maybe I didn't understand your question. What is the exact date pattern you like to match?

Comment: @vera no till now my focus is on date only I am telling that 2004 January is invalid date but it return trus as it consider 04 january

Comment: @madan Oh - got it. Sorry. I added a `\b` in front and back to the regex that should solve that problem. Please see the added demo for that.

Comment: @Vera thank you so much. I have one more thing to do if there is a year before and after the month then i have to consider those. Can you please update the answer? i.e. 2004 January is also a valid date

Comment: @madan I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. You gave samples that shouldn't match years. Do you have a sample that should match? Maybe `2004 January 10` and `10 January 2004` or do you mean that `10 January` will be interpreted as day and `2004 January` will be interpreted as year? That's all possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91055/discussion-between-madan-and-vera-rind).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
string pattern = "(([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) January)|(January ([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))";
```

Of course it will only work for January.